# Update listview on dropdownlist change - using causes validations and commandName

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a list of `ListView` Items of type `Place{Id,Label}`. In the last column, I have a `DropDownList` that helps me to select/set a new Label with the selected value.
Actualy I'm using a `DropDownList` and a Button

```
 <asp:DropDownList CssClass="edit_place_combobox" 
   ID="CollectiveBanksDropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" 
   DataSourceID="BanksObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="PlaceLabel" 
   DataValueField="PlaceID" Height="22px" Width="217px" />

 <asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="updatelabel" />
```

This works but I want to delete the button and trigger update when the `DropDownList` changes.

Is this possible in webform ?

Answer (score 1):

Drop down lists have "OnSelectedIndexChanged" which allows you to call a function in your backend code.

If your listview is wrapped with an update panel. All you need to do is call UpdatePanelName.Update() in the method you declared for "OnSelectedIndexChanged" in your dropdown list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx